# Toggling between 2 bookmarks (or see a page, and load another page from bookmark) won't work with jQuery History plugin

Tags: jquery, ajax, hashchange

Anyone knows how to fix this jQuery History plugin?  (for ajax history and bookmark)

In http://github.com/tkyk/jquery-history-plugin/issues#issue/5

This is the details:

My app using IE 8's IE 7 Compatibility Mode as well as http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/ajax, which is using IE 8's default mode, seem to have this problem:

Create 2 bookmarks

```
http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/ajax/#1
http://www.serpere.info/jquery-history-plugin/samples/ajax/#2
```

now click one bookmark, and try clicking the other, back and forth. The page content is not updated. In the current Firefox and Chrome, it works. In IE 8, it doesn't. Also true if you directly modify the hash value from #2 to #3

**P.S. I am quite sure it is solvable, because if using Facebook on IE 8,**

http://www.facebook.com/someusername?v=info#!/someusername?v=info
http://www.facebook.com/someusername?v=info#!/someusername?v=wall

works well if the user toggle between the 2 bookmarks.  (substitute someusername by some real user name above)

Answer (score 1):

Try balupton's [jQuery History](http://www.balupton.com/projects/jquery-history) plugin instead.