# The best Ajax History and Bookmark plugin currently available

Tags: jquery, ajax, hashchange, browser-state

It seems that each Ajax History and Bookmark plugin has some minor bugs, ranging from

Really Simple History
http://code.google.com/p/reallysimplehistory/

jQuery History plugin
http://www.mikage.to/jquery/history/rbbs.cgi?id=RA12733222240679954806&focus=1

Ajaxify
http://max.jsrhost.com/ajaxify/

The bug is either not firing off the event at all, thus the content is not changed, or the event is fired off twice (better than not firing off at all).  Is there an Ajax History and Bookmark plugin that work in all modern browsers?  (IE 7+, Chrome, Firefox, Safari)

jQuery History plugin seems to be best except it has this bug:
[Toggling between 2 bookmarks (or see a page, and load another page from bookmark) won't work with jQuery History plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242512/toggling-between-2-bookmarks-or-see-a-page-and-load-another-page-from-bookmark)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another vote for jQuery address. Super simple to use.

Answer (score 3):

[jQuery Address](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) looked good.  I haven't played much with any, so I can't verify that it is the best.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try this jQuery History plugin: http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-history/demo/ It provides cross browser support, binding to hashes, overloading hashes, all the rest.

There is also a Ajax extension for it, allowing it to easily upgrade your webpage into a proper Ajax application: http://www.balupton.com/sandbox/jquery-ajaxy/demo/

This is the solution chosen by such sites as http://wbhomes.com.au/ and http://gatesonline.com.au/stage/public/

Overall it is well documented, supported and feature rich. It's also won a bounty question here [How to show Ajax requests in URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3205900/how-to-show-ajax-requests-in-url/3276206#3276206)