# Ajax Pagination in PagedList.MVC using partial Page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, pagination, asp.net-ajax, pagedlist

PagedList.Mvc is working fine if I do not use partial page but when I use partial page with ajax to load the grid then there is problem in pagination.and I ended with the support from TroyGoode https://github.com/TroyGoode/PagedList/issues/26#issuecomment-6471793, But link provided for the support is not working.
Right now, I have used like this

```
@Html.PagedListPager((IPagedList)Model.MovieInforamtions, page => Url.Action("GetMovieDatabase", new { page }))
```

, which loads the page but I need to change the pagination ajaxically. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

This issue is solved by using [`PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing`](https://github.com/troygoode/PagedList/blob/master/src/PagedList.Mvc/PagedListRenderOptions.cs#L214).

```
@Html.PagedListPager(
    Model.MovieInforamtions, 
    page => Url.Action("GetMovieDatabase", new { page = page}),
    PagedListRenderOptions.EnableUnobtrusiveAjaxReplacing(new AjaxOptions(){  HttpMethod = "GET", UpdateTargetId = "movie_grid"})
)
```

Comment: Can you post the link to your project if present in GitHub or somewhere?

Comment: what if we want to **bookmark** example: page 2 , as  said [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20824965/2218697) in address bar query strings are not present on Ajax GET, is there any solution using ajax history [plugins](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3242644/the-best-ajax-history-and-bookmark-plugin-currently-available)?

Comment: This shows a blank page if user login session is timeout. How the ajax request response can be intercepted here to check the status?

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively , you can use jQuery Ajax to do so as below example.

https://github.com/ungleng/SimpleAjaxPagedListAndSearchMVC5

Answer (score 4):

The code works, but you need to add the reference to **jquery-unobtrusive-ajax.min.js** into your `main` view or `partial`.

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Answer (score -3):

People
This Code dosent Work
You Have To Add `Microsoft.Jauery.unobtrusive-ajax` To  Work
If You Don`t Add This Item Dose not Work